# SSRS - RDLC Tablix Rows will not split across pages

Tags: reporting-services

I have a tablix with two columns of data (the section name and the section text).  The section text has grown so large for some sections that the row representing the section takes up 2/3 or more of the page.  THe report prints fine until on of these large rows would have to split over the end of a page and continue on the next page.  In this case, and only in this case, the rows leaves large amounts of white space on current page and start on the next page (as if it had a page break before it)

I have already set the Tablix General Property "keep together on one page if possible" to true and all the other page break options for the tablix and row groups to false, to no avail.

Does anyone know of a trick or work around to make the large rows split over pages??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Setting `Keep together on one page if possible` to true/checked will cause SSRS to attempt to keep the row on one page, which means if the data spans across page breaks it will move that row to start on a new page so that it can be seen on one page, which would introduce white space where the row would be if the table was contiguous. So you need this setting set to `False/Unchecked`.

Next, ensure that the row group proeprty `Keep together` is set to `False`. This can't be accessed through the normal dialog box. If you don't have the properties pane showing in BIDS, then pressing `F4` will bring this pane up. Select the row group(s), and ensure the property is appropriately set.

Answer (score 6):

Also make sure that the text boxes inside the tablix are also set to KeepTogether=False.  This will fix the problem.