# blank space between tablix rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS 2008 report with tablix and one row need to show around 5000-6000 character but this row always move to next page leaving empty/blank space.

I have tired all options like keep togther on one page and i have tired taking row out of tablix and adding rectangle but no luck .

Can Someone help with some ideas. Thanks.

First Page showing some rows and then empty space

[image: First Page with empty space]

Row with large data is getting pushed to next page
[image: Second page showing 5000-6000 char]

Comment: Try to check your data, if it is html content then use placeholder to set data with html option

Comment: @rajesh. Yes that us html content and i have set placeholder as html but no luck.

Comment: Maybe try the answer posted to this question [ssrs-tablix-rows-will-not-split-across pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159932/ssrs-rdlc-tablix-rows-will-not-split-across-pages)?

Comment: can you also try to put all of them in one rectangle? just to hold them together.

Comment: Thanks all for your ideas but i fixed it but split data in 2 parts and then mapping to 2 different tablix rows.  i made an estimate about number of rows that can fit into 1st page then split data into 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are creating a letter with width 8.5 inch and height 11 inch. Assuming you have left 0.25 inch of border from all side; that leaves you with 8 inch of body width and 10.5 inch of height. Leave 1.5 inch for page header and 1 inch for page footer from 10.5 inch height. That leaves you with 8 inch of body height. Explicitly fix the height of Body to 8 inch. Once this is done, try to adjust you data within this space. I am sure, your issue will get resolved. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Pratik but content length can vary it can be in one page or 2 page.

Comment: the data gets accomodated accordingly...give it a try and let me know if you face any issues.